# How to setup altbeacon to prevent stoping scan when Android dozes

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, altbeacon, exposure

I have an Android app that implements an foreground service, uses a partial wakelock and has the permission to empty the battery by using `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` as explained here: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

That all works and the service runs forever without ever being put to doze.

My service uses ranging of beacons and permanently reports the distances. With altbeacon it nicely works. However, when the screen is switched off and after approx. 1 to 5 min, the Android power management somehow kicks in and the altbeacon library calls the 'RangeNotifier' callback always with an empty beacon list. Once that happens, beacon list is always empty, even if I wake the phone up again.

This is how I configure it:

```
beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this)
beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false)
beaconManager.isRegionStatePersistenceEnabled = false
beaconManager.foregroundBetweenScanPeriod = 0
beaconManager.foregroundScanPeriod = 1100
```

It somehow looks like the means I took to successfully evade the DOZE for my service are not extended to the Altbeacon service. How can I change this, and let altbeacon scan forever?

Edit:
The relevant section in the Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hollyhook.oscHook">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />

    <!-- for beacons -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity>
            ... removed for brevity
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".OscHookService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
         </service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

I'm testing with an Android 10 Samsung S10. I can provide an Android log with         `BeaconManager.setDebug(true)` if it helps (it is long and noisy)

Much thanks for any help!

Comment: [Update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65155295/edit) your question to include Android Manifest and on what devices are you testing on?

Comment: Just double checking that you've seen: https://dontkillmyapp.com/samsung

Comment: Yes, I found this out the hard way, after long debugging sessions blaming myself. Thanks! My foreground service stays awake, it sends UDP package every few milliseconds so I can really see it is ok (until battery is empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. As explained here:
https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/requesting_permission.html

Since target SDK 29+ accessing beacons in the background needs this permission declared in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```